# Shiny Error - User interactivity / input not working

Tags: r, shiny

Whenever I try to run an app that has interactivity (such as the the input shiny in the course notes), I get output similar to the below. I get the listening on http://... right after enter runApp(). I get the error as soon as open the URL page. I've tried to uninstall and reinstall both shiny and rtools. The only difference that I have seen as a result of my actions is that when I run app, where before it would open a browser window in chrome to the app, now it opens an R window that that immediately closes.

```
> runApp()

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5066
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
        headerPanel("Illustrating inputs"),
        sidebarPanel(
                numericInput('id1', 'Numeric input, labeled id1', 0, min = 0, max = 10, step = 1),
                checkboxGroupInput("id2", "Checkbox",
                                   c("Value 1" = "1",
                                     "Value 2" = "2",
                                     "Value 3" = "3")),
                dateInput("date", "Date:")  
        ),
        mainPanel(
                h3('Illustrating outputs'),
                h4('You entered'),
                verbatimTextOutput("oid1"),
                h4('You entered'),
                verbatimTextOutput("oid2"),
                h4('You entered'),
                verbatimTextOutput("odate")
        )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(
        function(input, output) {
                output$oid1 <- renderPrint({input$id1})
                output$oid2 <- renderPrint({input$id2})
                output$odate <- renderPrint({input$date})
        }
)
```

I'm using windows 7 and google chrome as my browser.

sessionInfo() returns the following:

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_0.10.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] bitops_1.0-6    caTools_1.17    digest_0.6.4    htmltools_0.2.4 httpuv_1.3.0   
[6] Rcpp_0.11.2     RJSONIO_1.3-0   tools_3.1.1     xtable_
```

Sys.info() output as follows [with user credentials removed]:

```
                 sysname                      release                      version 
               "Windows"                      "7 x64" "build 7601, Service Pack 1" 
                machine 
                "x86-64"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. It had to do with a function in my server file:

```
  observe(input$file1, {
       updateTabItems(session, "tabs", "upload")
   }
   )
```

I deleted it and everything is back to fine